# <input type='file'> not working in iphone for files with non-ascii name

Tags: iphone, file, file-upload, input, non-ascii-characters

I have a simple site with the following form:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file"/>
</form>
```

In Iphone, when I select a file which has a non-ascii name and look at the input's files object - the file name appears corrupted and the file size is 0.

Codepen I've tested with:
http://codepen.io/mayasc/pen/bgPQxa

Anyone know this issue? Got a solution? I found no occurrences of this no where.